# How to do local multiplayer in Gang Beasts on Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch, gang-beasts

It's our first time playing *Gang Beasts* and we are stuck at this screen.

[image: screenshot]

It's the Nintendo Switch version of the game. The game is [officially listed](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/gang-beasts-switch/) as supporting multiplayer of 1-4 players on a single system.

But there appears to be no way for the other three players to join.

We confirmed that all four Joy-Cons are paired.

We tried all the common methods of joining a multiplayer game with detached Joy-Cons:

- Pressing `+` or `-`
- Pressing and holding `L` and `R` simultaneously
- Shaking the Joy-Con

We have tried this both from the menu, and after starting with a single player.

We have tried various modes...but no luck.

We just want to do a local couch multiplayer battle. What do we do?

<sub>Everyone was stoked to play this game, but now it's total buzzkill.</sub>

### Edit:

I got it working by pressing the "accept" button on the non-P1 controllers. But I don't know why this didn't work before. I don't really have enough info to post a complete answer yet. In the meantime, someone else feel free.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an in-depth answer, but *basically* here's what you need to do:

<sup>(This answer assumes most players will be using the *detached Joy-Con* configuration.)</sup>

Each player should press the **Accept** button as soon as you reach the local multiplayer screen.

[image]

↑ In the above image, **Accept** would be **X**, and **Back** would be **A**.

Then use the **Left Thumb Stick** (↔ left and right directions) to choose an outfit.

Then press the **Accept** button again to accept your customization. Your character's arms will be raised in a "let's go!" position as soon as you do this.

Once all players have confirmed their choices, and their arms are raised, a countdown to gameplay will begin.

(At this point you still have a chance go **Back** if you want to change your configuration.)

It seems *some* options for Player 1 must be customized *before* entering this screen, but I need to study this more before I post info on it.